# Deletar arquivo por linha de comando com tipo diferente

Tags: windows, linha-de-comando, terminal

Tem 2 diretórios, o conteúdo deles é igual, mas em um deles só pode haver arquivos java

e no outro somente arquivos que não sejam java

Na pasta resources ficam aqueles não são java

> src\main\resources>del/s *.java

Na pasta java ficam somente os arquivos .java

> src\main\java>del/s ???

??? = todos os aquivos com extensão diferente de java

Comment: Sério que eu não entendi a pergunta nem o problema que você está tendo com o comando `del`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O comando `del` não deleta os arquivos somente leitura, a menos que você o force com `/f`.
Então, uma forma de deletar todos os arquivos menos os .java é tornar os .java somente leitura e depois retorná-los.

Tornar somente leitura:

```
cd src\main\java
attrib +r *.java
```

Deletar todos os arquivos (os .java vão ficar pois são somente leitura):

```
del /q *.*
```

Sendo o `/q` para que `cmd` não perguntar se você tem certeza.
Por fim, retorne os arquivos .java ao normal:

```
attrib -r *.java
```

---

Outra solução seria compiar os .java para uma outra pasta temporária e depois retorná-los a pasta str\main\java.

Algo tipo:

```
cd src\main\java
copy *.java TEMP_DIR
del *.* 
copy TEMP_DIR\*.java src\main\java
```

Comment: Boa jogada essa do `attrib`!